# ng-repeat not working in md-chip

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

Why is md-chip not supporting ng-repeat?

```
<md-chips>
          <md-chip data-ng-repeat="category in book.categories">
            {{category.name}}
          </md-chip>
        </md-chips>
```

Comment: I don't think so angular directives may depends upon HTML elements. You can use it anywhere. but will you please share your object structure ?

Comment: Testing independently, even this doesn't seem to be working.

<md-chips>
              <md-chip data-ng-repeat="number in [1,2,3]">
                {{number}}
              </md-chip>
            </md-chips>

Comment: `Will you please share your object structure ?`

Comment: This is a known issue: https://github.com/angular/material/issues/2829

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with angular 1.3.15 / angular-material 0.9.8, the following works here:

in the controller:

```
$scope.myNumbers = [ 1, 2, 3 ];
```

in the HTML:

```
  <md-chips ng-model="myNumbers" readonly="true">
  </md-chips>
```

Answer (score 7):

It seems I was looking for,

```
<md-chips ng-model="book.categories" readonly="true">
   <md-chip-template>
      <strong>{{$chip.name}}</strong>
   </md-chip-template>
</md-chips>
```

You bind it in ng-model to the md-chips tag instead of ng-repeat and then access the chip element by using $chip element inside the template tag.

Answer (score 5):

Use the md-chip-template instead of md-chip and use ng-model instead of ng-repeat.. like bellow.

```
<md-chips ng-model="user.skills" readonly="true">
    <md-chip-template>{{$chip.skill_title}}</md-chip-template>
</md-chips>
```

It should be work as your expectation.